# Howe can I have solution for pyperclip.paste() error in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

When I run following code;

```
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

It shows me following error.

```
C:\pyzo2015a\lib\site-packages\pyperclip\__init__.py in _copyWindows(text)
 46         text = text.decode('mbcs')
 47 
 48     d.user32.OpenClipboard(0 if PY2 else None)
 49 
 50     d.user32.EmptyClipboard()

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

What's the problem? I run this code using Python3 on Widows 7.